# What is the difference between grouping by two variables in the same line and in two subsequent lines?

Tags: r

I want to obtain all combinations of dog name and dog breed, and show how often they occur in the dataset. In doing so I noticed the following which I can't explain. When doing the grouping in the same line, it seems to give me what I want (the number of dogs with that exact combination, usually 1 or 2), but if I do it separately it gives me just the number of dogs with that breed, despite there being a grouping with respec to name. Why is this?

Here is my code. I ungrouped each time to try the different methods.

```
seattle_dogs %>%
  #group_by(animals_name) %>%
  #mutate(name_total = n()) %>%
  group_by(animals_name, primary_breed) %>%
  mutate(name_total = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(animals_name) %>%
  group_by(primary_breed) %>%
  mutate(name_total2 = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

[Here is an example from the resulting dataframe. Having the same species corresponds to the same value in name_total2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPTg.png)

Comment: It's difficult to examine the issue without a reproducible example dataset, but my guess is that the "animals_name" groups are replaced with the "primary_breed" groups when you perform 2 `group_by()` calls. Add the `.add = TRUE` argument to keep the previous groups.
Also, your code can be reduced to 2 lines if you use `count()`, e.g. `count(animals_name, primary_breed, name = "name_total")`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this difference is that the animal breed grouping replaces the animal name grouping. Simply add `.add = TRUE`.

```r
seattle_dogs %>%
  group_by(animals_name) %>%
  group_by(primary_breed, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(name_total2 = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or better yet..

```r
seattle_dogs %>%
  count(animals_name, primary_breed, name = "name_total")
```